# php include generated png in pdf via fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to generate a PDF with an image that is also generated by php.
Sounds simple enough and I am sure I'm just screwing up the header but I can't seem to find a solution here.

first I generate a PDF:

```
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','fonts/');
require('scpt/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {}
$pdf = new FPDF('P','in',array(8.5,11));
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false,0);

$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',12);

$pdf->Image('label.php?imgid=17',0,0,0,0,'PNG');

$pdf->Output('label.pdf','D');
```

then I generate the PNG in label.php:

```
if(isset($_GET["imgid"])) {
 header("Content-Type: image/png");
 $im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
     or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
 $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
 $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
 imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
 imagepng($im);
 imagedestroy($im);
}
```

This will output: `FPDF error: Not a PNG file:....`

calling label.php?imgid=17 in the browser however will show me the image just fine...

What am I missing?

EDIT

In document:
Example

```
// Insert a logo in the top-left corner at 300 dpi
$pdf->Image('logo.png',10,10,-300);
// Insert a dynamic image from a URL
$pdf->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',60,30,90,0,'PNG');
```

so it SHOULD be possible to include a dynamically generated image without saving it first?!

EDIT #2

I made it work with the library [mem_image](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script45.php) but the problem remains that this should not throw an error IMO?! So I leave this question open to see if there is indeed something wrong with my script of this turning out to be a bug.

Comment: This is a very broken down version of the code where I took the png code straight from the php.net site... So I am guessing that's not where the problem is...

Answer (score 2):

There is much better way without separate request, so without separate `label.php` to generate image, without any problems with permissions (like `allow_url_fopen`), headers, protocol handlers and so on. No need for 3-rd party scripts like `PDF_MemImage` as well.

You can just embed generated image in PDF directly using base64 data encoding. Here is an example for pure FPDF and PHP:

```
//// Create image
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20);

//...draw it with GD-functions like imagerectangle(), imagestring()

//// Get raw image data base64-encoded
//Begin capturing output buffer
ob_start();

// generate byte stream
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

// and finally retrieve output buffer content
$rawImageData = ob_get_clean();

// encode to base64
$imageData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode(rawImageData);

//// Add image it to PDF
$pdf->Image($imageData, 10, 10, 100, 100, 'png');
```

Useful links:

- Output buffering: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php , https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php
- base64 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php
- FPDF Image() http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, you're missing only a couple things. First you need the full server address in the URL for your Image() call, so instead of

```
$pdf->Image('label.php?imgid=17',0,0,0,0,'PNG');
```

You need:

```
$pdf->Image('http://www.yourserver.com/label.php?imgid=17',0,0,0,0,'PNG');
```

That will eliminate the FPDF error you were encountering. Then to get FPDF to render your output correctly, you need to add a call to AddPage(), so your PDF generation script would become:

```
require('scpt/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P','in',array(8.5,11));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('http://www.yourserver.com/label.php?imgid=17',0,0,0,0,'PNG');

$pdf->Output('label.pdf','D');
```

Of course you don't need the SetTextColor(), SetFont(), etc if you're only including the single  image. You didn't need the custom class definition either (I removed the unneeded lines).

Don't forget to substitute `www.yourserver.com` for the appropriate domain and path for your script.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the Image function needs to be a file, not a URL or another script. Since you already have your label script, the easiest work around would be to download the image to a temp location and then call $pdf->Image() with that temporary file.

Comment: well I was trying to get around this as I would have to write a GC for that case...

Comment: As explained in the FPDF docs, the Image function accepts a URL as for the image source, as well as a path to a local file. See the docs here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred With your file name,Make sure your passing file name is valid

```
function _parsepngstream($f, $file)
{
// Check signature
if($this->_readstream($f,8)!=chr(137).'PNG'.chr(13).chr(10).chr(26).chr(10))
    $this->Error('Not a PNG file: '.$file);

...
}
```

Comment: not sure what you mean but this is a simplified example and `Image()` has found the file (otherwise it would give me a `stream failed` exception.

Comment: I did not know we should pass some GET parameter like an example or not.


// Insert a dynamic image from a URL
$pdf->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',60,30,90,0,'PNG');

Comment: again not entirely sure what you mean but you are making a very important point: the manual talks about a dynamic image: `// Insert a dynamic image from a URL
$pdf->Image('http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World',60,30,90,0,'PNG');` so it SHOULD be possible right?

Comment: I am sorry Dominik, I am not sure too,but Just try to give you a tip.

Comment: I found interesting link: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/161687-fpdf-error-not-a-jpeg-file-mysiteimglogojpg/

Comment: the png does not have an alpha channel ... and fpdf 1.7 now supports alpha anyway...

Comment: I did try this as well but it also throws and error so I came back to this version thinking it should work anyway...

Answer (score 0):

View allow_url_fopen directive

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Answer (score 0):

You need to do only changes that

```
require('fpdf.php');
```

and do the

```
$pdf->Image('http://www.yourserver.com/label.php?imgid=17',0,0,0,0,'PNG');
```

and run your code...

Answer (score 0):

**First**, try to check your url with this code

$handle = fopen("http://www.yourserver.com/label.php?imgid=17", "rb");

print_r(fread($handle, 8192));

you with see what the contain in your url

**) make sure your url is not redirect to the login page

Answer (score -1):

much more easy, only put .png in the final of dinamic chain and its all

example:

```
$pdf->Image('http://www.yourserver.com/label.php?   imgid=17.png',0,0,0,0,'PNG');
```

or

```
$pdf->Image('../label.php?imgid=17.png',0,0,0,0,'PNG');
```

the mime type is not recognized in the url why does not appear png, if it's a stupid mistake but it is proven, google does the same by adding the extension with the url & PNG

Comment: so you are saying the URL string needs to end in `.png` to somehow make fpdf know to honor its header? Sounds dodgy to me but I'll try it when I have some time and report back.