# how should i display image from php mysql to fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, image, fpdf

can anyone help me how to display my save image from mysql database to fpdf using select function of mysql.

this is my codes:

```
<?php


                            if (isset($_GET['id']))
                            {
                        $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root',"");
                        if (!$con)
                          {
                          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                          }

                        mysql_select_db("mcndb", $con);

                        $id = $_GET['id'];

                     $pen ="pending";



                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblfinalorder WHERE id = '$id' && status  LIKE '{$pen}%' ");
                        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {


                   $trans=  $row2['transnum'];
                    $item=  $row2['itemnum'];   
                      $pic= $row2['attachko'];               





    mysql_close($con);
                        }



require ('FPDF/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$testingkolang= new FPDF('P','mm','legal');
$testingkolang->AddPage('P'); 



$testingkolang->Image('FPDF/logona.png',85,1,40,20,'PNG');

$testingkolang->SetFont('Times','B','10');
$testingkolang ->SetXY(50, 25); 
$testingkolang->Write(1,"#15C Mindanao Avenue Extension,Corner Palmera St. Talipapa, Quezon City."); 

$testingkolang->SetFont('Times','B','10');
$testingkolang ->SetXY(20,35); 
$testingkolang->Write(0,"Transaction Number:  ".$trans); 

$testingkolang->SetFont('Times','B','10');
$testingkolang ->SetXY(100,35); 
$testingkolang->Write(0,"Item Number:  ".$item); 

$testingkolang->SetFont('Times','B','10');
$testingkolang ->SetXY(100,35); 
$testingkolang->Write(0,"Item Number:  ".$item);


$testingkolang->Output();


?>
```

Note: my variable name there for my image from database to show is  $pic= $row2['attachko'];    can anyone help me how to show the image there?

this is the current working pdf of that code

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO33m.jpg)

what i want to know is how to diplay the image from the database under the line of transaction number as shown in the picture.

Comment: stop using the depreciated MySQL API

Comment: @Dagon  and what should i use? then how to display image from database in what are you referring to? pls i need answer

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO_MySQL see http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php  But this is tangential to your question.

Comment: I think you'll need to use PHP to generate the image file from the MySQL binary field and then use the fpdf Image function to put it in your pdf.  See this question for more help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987894/php-include-generated-png-in-pdf-via-fpdf

Comment: Alternately, you could look at this library which allows you to use in memory images: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script45.php

Comment: @scotru i already look at that memory images function but i dont really get  on how will i put it in my codes. if you dont mind can you please help me with this base on my codes given above? help will really be appriciated

Comment: i mean can i display image in from database to php like this one <?php   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($accounts['attachko']).'" class="img-square" height="100px" width="100px" id="image"> ';
 ?>  because thats what i use in generating image from database but it doesnt work on fpdf